# Can sklearn's Random Forest Classifier choose a 'default' classification if uncertain?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm using RandomForestClassifier for a three-class problem. Using predict_proba(), these are the first 5 outputs:

> [0.342, 0.31 , 0.348],
>
> [0.529, 0.24 , 0.231],
>
> [0.398, 0.324, 0.278],
>
> [0.438, 0.194, 0.368],
>
> [0.356, 0.146, 0.498],

Can I change the threshold for the decision? I have another set of predictions for this data and would like to default to those predictions in cases like the first instance, where the probabilities don't suggest a decisive 'winner'.

Comment: I think you need to do it manually.